# Integrate laravel project into existing non laravel website

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am going to make a backupscript in Laravel 5.2 for an existing website.
The url is going to be for example www.domain.com/makebackup/ (unique) and activate by a crontask.

How can i integrate this? I hope aomeone can give me advise!

Comment: You can use a package such as [spatie/laravel-backup](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup)

Comment: @piscator i already have a backup script in Laravel, but i want to integrate this into an existing websapplication with a index.php, how can i do that?

Comment: Is an entire web application framework like Laravel not a bit overkill for a small task like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use any framework for the first project, you can make a separate dir inside and put laravel app in it. If you are using a framework, do the same, but use an .htaccess rewrite for the backup url.